# HEX AES Encryption in Mysql and PHP

Tags: mysql, aes

I have some questions, first, what is faster, use `HEX` and `AES_ENCRYPT` in MySQL or first encrypt data and convert it to hex in PHP, then insert result in MySQL database.

The other question, exist a MySQL connection method more faster than `mysqli()`? I am using `new mysqli()` to connect, `$mysqli->query()` to send a query, and `$mysqli->fetch_assoc()['column'];` to get a response and I need more speed.

And finally, exist a simplification method for `AND`?, from `OR` is `IN()` but for `AND`, I dont know.

Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: If you need more speed, it is almost certainly due to a slow query than a slow MySQL client API.  If you need help optimizing the `SELECT` statement that isn't fast enough, post it and we can assist you.

Comment: But no, there's no correlate for `IN ()` that implements `AND` instead of `OR`, because `IN ()` operates across multiple rows but an `AND` condition operates on a single row. There are ways to enforce all values in an `IN()` using additional aggregates, but it isn't like a shortcut for multiple `AND`. Depends what you need - post your code please.